# Some emojis are not displayed correctly in color in Word

Tags: microsoft-word

Why do some emojis appear as black-and-white Unicode characters, while others appear as modern emojis in Microsoft Word (on Windows)?

Is there a way to fix this? Preferably I would like to display modern emojis.

[image]